# Function not working with interface

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small class Student that implements an interface. Problem is when the ADD() function gets called from the windows form and as soon as it reaches the code where the Update() function is being called, the DataTable _dtable (declared locally) gets null. The code works fine if I call the Update() function from the form instead of the class.

This is the first time I am asking any question on this site, so I don't know the rules but if I can ask two questions, then I'd like to know the best way for data manipulation, both connection oriented and disconnected. The method I am using doesn't look very practical since I am not using any SQL stored procedures. A link to some tutorial would be great.

Form:

```
void IForm.SaveData(DBCommandType mode)
{
    if (mode == DBCommandType.INSERT)
    {
        _std.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        _std.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        _istd.Add();
    }
    else if (mode == DBCommandType.UPDATE)
    {
        _istd.Update(_rowPosition);
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
 int IStudent.Add()
 {
     int rowPosition;
     int result;
     Student std = new Student();
     IStudent istd;
     istd = (IStudent)std;
     DataRow drNewRow = _dtable.NewRow();
     _dtable.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
     rowPosition = _dtable.Rows.Count - 1;
     //_dtable holds it value before the Update() function gets called.
     result = istd.Update(rowPosition);
     return 1;
 }

int IStudent.Update(int _rowPosition)
{
    int result =0;
    if (_dtable.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        _dtable.Rows[_rowPosition]["FirstName"] = this.FirstName;
        _dtable.Rows[_rowPosition]["LastName"] = this.LastName;
        result = _dbc.UpdateDataTable();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While updating rows from table ensure that there is a row before updating.

**Replace following :**

```
     result = istd.Update(rowPosition);
```

**with :**

```
 if(rowPosition > -1)
    result = istd.Update(rowPosition);
```

Comment: Care to explain a little?

Comment: Thanks @Sudhakar for the suggestion. I am still getting the same error. In debug mode, it shows me that there are 4 records but as soon as it calls Update() the _dtable gets clear and set to null. If I call the same thing from the FORM instead of Class, it works fine.